# Filtering date in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

i am trying to filter date by month  in Crystal Reports Formula but its not working 
 Here is the Formula

```
 {Employees.d_o_b} = "yyyy-09-dd"
```

in database date is saved in this format

```
 2013-09-29
```

in a Date type filed i am using Sql Server 2008 and Crystal Reports 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Correct formula

```
 MONTH(DATE({Employees.d_o_b})) = 09
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
MONTH({Employees.d_o_b}) = "09"
```

Comment: Error : A date is Required . . .

Answer (score 0):

```
MONTH(cDate({Employees.d_o_b})) = 09
```